# How to view image in browser using HTML

Tags: html

I am new in programming. I *unable to view* the image in browser.
My *code block* is :

```
<P>Hello all</p>
<img src="C:/Users/admin/Documents/hr1.jpg" alt="image" width="110" height="170">
```

But it not showing image in browser.
Please help me how to set path of image.

Comment: What error you get? find out by pressing F12. Also check in another browser too..

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to use is an img tag that's all. Check out the code below.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <img src="imageToShow.jpg" alt="text related to image" width="42" height="42">

    </body>
    </html>
```

I would also suggest you to read more on

http://www.w3schools.com/

The site is very helpful for beginners.

Comment: Sorry i am using this also i dont know why my image is not showing in browser..simply i did this:<!DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
<Head>
<title>
this site for all...
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to this site..</h1>

<P>Hello all</p>
<img src="Tulips.jpeg" alt="image text" width="110" height="170"></img>
</body>

</Html>

Comment: can you try tulips.jpg, and see if solves your problem. Also check if image name is also 'Tulips' not 'tulips'. As image sources are case sensitive.

And make sure your image file is in the same folder of your html file.

If your image file is in a different folder, then you will need to mention the path.

Comment: I already  checked this case sensitive issue but i type it ok. also i learn more things from w3school. but i dint understand exactly what is problem. I want to know my HTML file stored in documents folder & image also stored in documents folder then what is the problem.

Comment: if image and .html files are in same folder then no need of absolute path, you can just mention <img src="hr1.jpg"> , if you mention the absolute path it is not a problem though.

Comment: You can troubleshoot easily if you can just view inspect element in your browser and check if your path is correct or not. Also right click on the path and click open in new tab, see if your image appears or not. If not you can easily correct the path from browser URL

Comment: Ohh thanks..Its working now. i just change the browser & it will solve.

Answer (score 0):

You only required `<img>` tag from `html` tags  between `body` to display an image.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>MyFirst Web Page</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <h1>Hello all</h1>
 <img src="filename.jpg/jpeg/png/gif" alt="image text" width="30" height="30"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

@Sam Your file didn't found your given File location you provide local path but file is not their (Tulips.jpg)

Do either save file where image is available

either give full path reference of image like

```
 src="c:\user\systemuser\desktop\imageToShow.jpg"
```